# Can someone explain me the following prime number generation method?

Tags: java, primes

I guess the method below uses *Sieve of Eratosthenes* (inclusion-exclusion algorithm) to generate prime numbers up to a given number.
What I specifically don't understand, is why it clears bits set on the `(j/2)` position. Is there a specific rule that is followed?  The `BitSet` contains bits set at position x and this number is either prime number or is composite. So, I am not able to follow what is going on.

```
public static List<Integer> generatePrimes(int max) {
        BitSet primeSet = new BitSet(max / 2);
        primeSet.set(1, max / 2);
        int limit = (int) Math.sqrt(max);
        for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2) {
            if (!primeSet.get(i / 2)) continue;
            for (int j = i * i; j < max; j += i * 2)
                primeSet.clear(j / 2);

        }

        List<Integer> listOfPrimes = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfPrimes.add(2);
        for (int i = primeSet.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = primeSet.nextSetBit(i + 1)) {
            listOfPrimes.add(i * 2 + 1);
        }
        return listOfPrimes;
    }
```

Comment: the sieve of E. is not an inclusion-exclusion type of algorithm. a number twice excluded stays excluded, in the sieving algorithm. In inc-exc type of algorithm, it'd have to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bits of the primeset represent the numbers 2x+1 where x is the index of the bitset. Thus, when your primeset contains {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14} they represent the numbers {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29}.

If you're interested in programming with prime numbers I modestly recommend [this essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog. Among other things, it explains the Sieve of Eratosthenes and the calculation that is causing you grief.

EDIT: Add simple Sieve of Eratosthenes as explained in comment.

```
function primes(n)
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n step 1
        if sieve[p]
            output p
            for i from p * p to n step p
                sieve[i] := False
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you need to represent the numbers as 2x+1 and not do it directly on the loop? Did not find the answer in your essay, reading it for the second time now.

Comment: Because you only include odd numbers in the bitset. In the essay, see the two paragraphs before and after Algorithm 1.B, especially the paragraph after. I don't understand your question "directly on the loop."

Comment: I ment why do we need the second loop and not just try to add the primes in the first loop.

Comment: @mark: You could compute the primes in the first loop. I've edited my answer to show a Sieve of Eratosthenes that I routinely use. It doesn't have the odd-only optimization, but it's simple and clear.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the algorithm is trying to conserve memory by having `primeSet` represent odd numbers *only*. Hence the repeated multiplications and divisions by two.

The loop involving `primeSet.clear()` simply marks every multiple of `i` as composite.

Comment: it is not only odd numbers. When I call this method with 1000 as max, the bits set in the primeset are:
{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14}
So it is mix of odd and even numbers. That is why I dont understand.

Comment: @mark: When bit `k` is set, this means that `2*k+1` is prime. Thus, {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, ...} means that the numbers 2*1+1=3, 2*2+1=5, 3*2+1=7, 5*2+1=11, 6*2+1=13, ... are prime.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static List<Integer> generatePrimes(int max) {

 BitSet primeSet = new BitSet(max / 2);  // host the numbers i up to max/2
 primeSet.set(1, max / 2);               // representing the odds (2i+1)
 int limit = (int) Math.sqrt(max);       //                      below max
 for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2)        // enumerate odds in range 
 {                                          //       3 .. sqrt(max)
     if (!primeSet.get(i / 2)) continue;    // i=2k+1, i/2==(2k+1)/2== k
                                            // (here i is value, k is index)
     for (int j = i * i; j < max; j += i * 2)  // j=i*i is the first multiple
         primeSet.clear(j / 2);        // of i, where the marking off begins
 }                                     //  with step 2*i: 3: 9,6,15,21,...
                                       //                 7: 49,63,77,91,...
 List<Integer> listOfPrimes = new ArrayList<>();
 listOfPrimes.add(2);                     // 2 is known to be prime a priori
 for (int i = primeSet.nextSetBit(0);     // starting with first set bit in
                                          //                 BitSet primeSet,
          i >= 0;                         // 1: until the end of primeSet  
          i = primeSet.nextSetBit(i + 1)  // 3: and go to next set bit
          ) {
     listOfPrimes.add(i * 2 + 1);         // 2: add 2i+1 to the list of primes,
 }                                        // (here i is index)
 return listOfPrimes;
}
```

As part of the sieve we must mark each third number among odds starting from 9, and in general each *n*th number, starting from *n*<sup>2</sup>, as apparently one [Rev. Samuel Horsley F.R.S. knew back in 1772](http://www.jstor.org/stable/106053?seq=8).

It is inefficient to just count along the list – the key to sieve's efficiency is the direct access to memory by address. This address of a number in an array of numbers here is just the number's value itself (this *conflation of value and address* is also the key to the efficiency of various integer sorting methods).

To directly calculate each 3rd odd number, we must add 6 to the previous one to get the next. For each 5th we add 10, and for each `i`th – `2*i`.

---

Incidentally this code can be slightly improved. For numbers at the distance `2*i` between them, the indices in the set will be at the distance of `i`. No need to delete by 2 all the time, just calculate the starting index and increment by `i`.

---

edit: that code is equivalent to the following pseudocode:

```
defn primes(max):
  sieve := makeArray(3,5,7 ... max, True)
  for p from 3 to sqrt(max) step 2:
    if sieve[p]:
        for i from p * p to max step 2*p:
            sieve[i] := False
  primes = {2} + {all i in (3,5,7, ... max) such that sieve[i] is True}
```

Comment: The reason for my confusion was exactly that, I mixed the position in the bitset with the actual value (prime).

Answer (score 1):

All even numbers except 2 are not prime so there is no need for iterating over them.